# Fixed space/width printing of variables in shell

Tags: shell, fixed-width

I have made a tabular report of some data variables printed via printf in shell.

```
Project One    | 76   | 80M    | 80M    | 80M 
Project Two    | 46M  | 52M    | 52M    | 52M 
Project Three  | 174  | 171M   | -      | 173M
```

The output here is a manually spaced one.
Is there a way to print variables that occupies fixed width?

For example, in the first row, 76[space], 80M, ... total of three character width with printing with a shell variable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understood what you want is a function to leave certain number of spaces after a specified string. Here it is:

```
fix_space() {
    string="$1"
    len="$2"
    perl -e "my \$str = '`printf "$string" | sed "s/'/\\'/g"`'; print \$str.' ' x ($len - length(\$str))"
}
echo "'`fix_space "ololfdsaf" 20`'"
echo "'`fix_space "ololff" 20`'"
```

It simply makes `perl` doing all the dirty job. String goes as the first argument, and the full length as the second. I am sure this will help you to align your output.

#### EDIT:

You can do it without `perl` with only using shell. Then you have to type:

```
printf "'$string`printf ' '%.0s {1..$((len - ${#string}))}`'\n"
```

#### Reference

http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Repeat_a_string#UNIX_Shell

Comment: Let us not call that pearl a dirty job; because it works now as I wished. I will use it. Thanks.

Comment: @BimalPoudel, I extended the answer in case you bother time consumption. Using printf is a faster.